# Atomic Packing Fraction

Tags: crystal-structure, entropy, atomic-physics

I need to calculate excess entropy of mixing for a particular system of alloy. The excess entropy of mixing is dependent on temperature and it takes into account this temperature dependence by using atomic packing fraction. I wanted to know once the alloy solidifies, will there be any change in the atomic packing fraction on reducing the temperature?

Comment: This seems like a very tough question (at least for me). So perhaps can you provide more info.  To start is this a software-request question i.e. do you want to know what software tools you can use to analyze atomic packing fraction? That would be a simpler question to ask, and we have a tag for such questions, then the actual hypothesis you are trying to test